# SSL peer shut down incorrectly

Tags: java, ssl

This is my first post here. I am a hobbyist so please bear with me.

I am attempting to to grab a webpage from https://eztv.it/shows/1/24/ with the following code.

```
public static void WriteHTMLToFile(String URL){
    try {

        URI myURI=new URI(URL);
        URL url = myURI.toURL();
        HttpsURLConnection con= (HttpsURLConnection)url.openConnection();
        File myFile=new File("c:\\project\\Test.txt");
        myFile.createNewFile();
        FileWriter wr=new FileWriter(myFile);
        InputStream ins=con.getInputStream();
        InputStreamReader isr= new InputStreamReader(ins);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(isr);
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            wr.write(line+"\n");    
        }

        reader.close();
        wr.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        log(e.toString());
        }   
}
```

When I run this I get the following:

> javax.net.ssl.SSLException: SSL peer shut down incorrectly

If I run the above code on this URL: https://eztv.it/shows/887/the-blacklist/ it works as intended. The difference between the two URL file sizes seems to be a contributing factor. In testing different URLs to the same server the above code only seemed to work for files less that ~30Kb. Anything over would generate the above exception.

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out. The server is responding with gzip encoding once file sizes are over a certain size.

`con.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate, sdch");`

was added to the request header as well as some code to handle the gzip stream.

Comment: Do you mean that the server closes the connection above a certain size *unless* you permit it to use gzip encoding?

Answer (score 0):

if small file can run ,but large file  get the following:
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: SSL peer shut down incorrectly

mabey  Nginx
(crit 20033#0: *563 open()"home/nginx/proxy temp/8/03/0000000038" failed (13: Permission denied) while reading upstream

This reason may be because a temporary file will be generated when the forwarding exceeds the configuration. This temporary file may be caused by no permission, so give this temporary file the right to modify

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).